# Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: github, nuxt.js, github-actions, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt 3 app that auto-deploys to Deno Deploy via GitHub Action. Today, after a commit to the main branch, workflow began to fall:

```
[success] Server built in 7521ms
[success] [nitro] Generated public .output/public
[info] [nitro] Initializing prerenderer
[info] [nitro] Prerendering 1 routes
[log] [nitro]   ├─ /api/_content/cache.1690626485326.json (1414ms)
[info] [nitro] Building Nitro Server (preset: `deno-deploy`)

<--- Last few GCs --->

[2052:0x6a65f60]    77941 ms: Mark-sweep 2000.7 (2080.7) -> 1996.3 (2093.3) MB, 1926.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.525, current mu = 0.107) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
[2052:0x6a65f60]    80549 ms: Mark-sweep 2012.1 (2093.3) -> 2006.6 (2102.6) MB, 2569.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.297, current mu = 0.015) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb83f50 node::Abort() [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
 2: 0xa94834  [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
 3: 0xd647c0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
 4: 0xd64b67 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
 5: 0xf42265  [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
 6: 0xf5474d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
 7: 0xf2ee4e v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
 8: 0xf30217 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
 9: 0xf113ea v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
10: 0x12d674f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
11: 0x17035b9  [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.17.0/x64/bin/node]
Aborted (core dumped)
error Command failed with exit code 134.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 134.
```

On the local machine, the application builds without problems. The commits I made were for setting up Sentry and Nuxt Image. That is, I did not add anything that could exceed the limit in memory. And by the way, in the end I rolled back these changes to the last successful build - it did not help.

Tell me, please, how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
- name: Build application
  run: yarn build
  env:
    NODE_OPTIONS: "--max_old_space_size=4096"
    NITRO_PRESET: deno-deploy
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.